Does field isomorphism preserve order relation?
Let $(F,+_\mathrm{f},\cdot_\mathrm{f},<_\mathrm{f})$ and $(G,+_\mathrm{g},\cdot_\mathrm{g},<_\mathrm{g})$ be two ordered fields. Let $f:F\to G$ be a field isomorphism. (So, $f$ is bijective, and preserves the two operations, the two identities, and the two inverse functions.)
Does this imply that $f$ also preserves the order relation? In other words, do we have: $x <_\mathrm{f} y$ if and only if $f(x) <_\mathrm{g} f(y)$ for any $x\in F$ and $y\in F$?
I am looking for a simple proof or counterexample. Or perhaps you could point me to a book or paper that contains such a simple proof or counterexample. Thanks!

No. $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ for example has two automorphisms, one of which doesn't preserve order.

@Mark Why not an official answer?

@PaulFrost I added an answer.

The answer is no. $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ has an automorphism $a+b\sqrt{2}\to a-b\sqrt{2}$ (for $a,b\in\mathbb{Q}$) that does not preserve order.

Great, thanks for your answer!
